# Configuring PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer for WAR

Tags: java, spring, properties, war

I am trying to create a WAR that can use a spring properties file, but I seem to be having some issues with it.

I can see that my properties file in the base directory structure in target, and in a WAR when I make an exploded war. When I try to make a normal WAR, though, and deploy it, I a resource not found exception, specifically:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [service.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

From Jetty I have no such issue.

Here's my spring java configuration of the resource:

```
@Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer() {

        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer props = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        props.setLocations(new Resource[] { new ClassPathResource("service.properties") });
        return props;
    }
```

And here's the relevant part of my POM. I added in the WAR configuration because that's what maven seemed to say to do [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html), but it didn't seem to help.

```
<build>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/config/local</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.properties</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3</version>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>war</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <webResources>
                                <resource>
                                    <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                                    <directory>src/main/config/local</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/*.properties</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </webResources>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that your properties file is inside `WEB-INF` folder? If it outside and is just included in the root of the war file then it won't be found in the classpath. See [maven-war-plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html#Overriding_the_default_destination_directory) - to override default location (root of the war file) you need to add

```
<targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
```